# PHP 8.0 and SAPNWRFC build on windows

Tags: xampp, php-8, saprfc, sapnwrfc

I'm currently trying to implement the library in PHP 8.0 but I find the following error while adding extension file (DLL) on xampp "sapnwrfc.dll':

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Can't load module 'C:\xampp\php\ext\sapnwrfc.DLL' as it's linked with 12.0, but the core is linked with 14.29 in Unknown on line 0

Anyone, have you managed to compile the DLL for PHP 8.0, and be able to use `sapnwrfc` extension file on PHP?